# Creating a SQL statement based on existing table fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a table populated with databases and table names, is it possible to create some dynamic query based on those fields? Something like:

```
DECLARE @mysearch NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT db_name, tbl_name FROM UserConfig where ID = 1';

SELECT * FROM [db_name]..[tbl_name]
```

Being *db_name* and *tbl_name* the result values of *@mysearch* query.

For clarification, database and table names from where I need to select data are in a table, not hardcoded.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM MYDB..MyTable
```

But "MYDB" and "MyTable" are values stored somewhere else.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I follow here. How to `@mysearch` and the latter `SELECT`relate? What is your end goal here?

Comment: Database and table names from where I need to 'select * from'  are in a table, not hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading a lot through the lines here, but are you *actually* after this?

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
              N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(db_name) + N'.dbo.' + QUOTENAME(tbl_name) + N';'
FROM UserConfig
WHERE ID = 1;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This **assumes** a single row would be returned for a single value of `ID` in the table `UserConfig`.

Comment: What if the table has multiple rows?

Comment: What table, @FilipeYaBaPolido ? This assumes either could.

Comment: In this case, "userconfig", I've tried this and the dynamic query only returns data from one table in userconfig.

Comment: Because `ID = 1` is a acalar comparison. If you want this to work with an `IN ` you need to ask a new question.